# Store an "as a file tree represented" file system

Tags: java, tree, persistence

I have file system represented in Java as a tree architecture (based on a composite pattern) - now there might be situations were the file system holds several hundreds or thousand of files and there might be a lot of activity (delete, modify, etc.) - the application should be able to store at any time a copy of the tree in a file (e.g. xml) - I tested so far XStream which works fine but it writes for every file event a complete new file, which will slow down the system when there are hundreds of events in a short time period...

Does anyone know a better approach?

Comment: Maybe you can treat it like a version control system: Have a baseline and only store change operations.  Bring the tree to any particular state by applying all the changes in order as needed.

Comment: Wait, you want to serialize all your filesystem in XML? Just a question... Why? What are you doing with such a dump?

Comment: @fge - with file system I mean a root folder and some subfolders which are monitored by my application - not the entire file system of an operating system. there is no particular reason for it. I just started with something I know and tested it. What would you suggest?

Comment: Well, I can't suggest anything unless I know what is the intent behind this dump. Also, what is the original filesystem? An on disk filesystem? Other?

Comment: @fge, the application is a P2P sharing tool for enterprise purposes, so it monitors a root folder and subfolders which may contains files. If the monitoring application fails, it must be possible to restart it and detect any new modification which might happen in between. for that it needs a comparable version (e.g. an xml dump of the entire tree).

Comment: Hmm, and how is it monitored? Using java.nio.file and a WatchService? As to diffs, I'd just use JSON and JSON Patch instead of XML; look for instance [here](https://github.com/fge/json-patch): it is able to generate diffs between two JSONs; or you can generate patches yourself

Comment: yes, I am using java.nio.file and a WatchService. Thanks for the reference - I'll check it out.